# SQL Query to list related records to array of values in a single field

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I need a result set from two tables where one table has a field named Subjects with an array of values (1,2,3, etc.). Those values will match the PK in a Subjects table. I need to replace the numeric values with the subject names.

Given two tables:

Students:

```
ID:100,FNAME:Steve,SUBJECTS:2,3
ID:101,FNAME:Billy,SUBJECTS:1,2
```

Subjects:

```
ID:1,SUBJECT:Math
ID:2,SUBJECT:Reading
ID:3,SUBJECT:Spelling
```

Need SQL syntax to produce:

```
ID:100,FNAME:Steve,SUBJECTS:Reading, Spelling
ID:101,FNAME:Billy,SUBJECTS:Math, Reading
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, yet? Any code that you can show us?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Can you change the schema and create a cross-reference table?

Comment: Are you stuck with that table schema, or can you burn it to the ground and start fresh?

Comment: Is the "array" in fact a ```SET``` or just a concatenated string?

Comment: As luksch and Nick Vaccaro hinted, it's best to not include multiple values in one field. Investigate [`database normalization`](http://searchbusinessintelligence.techtarget.in/tutorial/Database-normalization-in-MySQL-Four-quick-and-easy-steps).

Comment: Thanks. MYSQL. Yes I know it is not normalized. I can burn it, change it. But I do have to end up with that list in my result, matching Subject Names listed comma separated in the same result row. I bet if I normalize, get a result, I can then use my programing language to loop through the records to get my Subject Names lined up.

Comment: luksch, the list is a string, stored in the table as shown in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Students.ID, Students.FNAME, GROUP_CONCAT(Subjects.SUBJECT) 
FROM Students, Subjects 
WHERE Students.SUBJECTS LIKE CONCAT('%',Subjects.ID,'%') 
GROUP BY Students.ID;
```

[see my sqlfidde](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7857b/9)

Note that this is highly inefficient. You should really create a cross-reference table ind use normal `JOINS`.

As Gordon Linoff pointed out, it might be even better to use `find_in_set` which works at least for MySql:

```
SELECT Students.ID, Students.FNAME, GROUP_CONCAT(Subjects.SUBJECT separator ', ') 
FROM Students join
     Subjects
     on find_in_set(subjects.id, students.subjects) > 0
GROUP BY Students.ID;
```

[improved fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7857b/11/1)

Comment: The sqlfiddle does not match what the OP asked for.

Comment: luksch, that worked beautifully. I got the message that it is inefficient, so I will work on the normalization.

Comment: BTW, long time user of stackOverflow, but this is my first question. I had no idea experts would pounce on the question so quickly, thank you very much for the input. My specialty is building web/mobile apps with Alpha Five, with less skill on SQL.

Comment: @Marichyasana i suggest you improve it then!

Answer (score 1):

A nice MySQL way to do this is:

```
SELECT Students.ID, Students.FNAME, GROUP_CONCAT(Subjects.SUBJECT separator ', ') 
FROM Students join
     Subjects
     on find_in_set(subject.id, students.subjects) > 0
GROUP BY Students.ID;
```

However, your data structure is just begging for a StudentSubjects table, instead of storing the list of subjects as ids.  A third table is the proper way to store this information in a relational database.